# Is there a way to search the starting character positions of all matching strings in a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

Suppose that in cell A2 in my spreadsheet, I have the phrase "The doctor and the nurse". The function SEARCH("the", A2) would return the value 1, which indicates that "the" is found and that it starts at character 1. However, this will not tell me whether there are other the's, and in this case, there is a 2nd "the". Nor will it tell me the starting index of the 2nd "the".

So I wonder if there is a way to retrieve all starting character positions of matching strings in a cell. I know this can be easily achieved in a programming language, but for the present task I am dealing with, I can only use Excel.

Comment: Google: find and mid functions in excel

Comment: I don't think FIND and MID do what I want to do

Comment: I have a megaformula that will return an array of all the starting positions. In the example above, it would return {1;16}. Will that work?

Comment: @rwilson: Yes, it would definitely work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another set of formulas that will return an array of all the starting positions of `search_for` in `string`

**Case Sensitive**

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(string,search_for,CHAR(1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(string) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(string,search_for,"")))/LEN(search_for)))))
```

**Case Insensitive**

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(string),LOWER(search_for),CHAR(1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(string) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(string),LOWER(search_for),"")))/LEN(search_for)))))
```

If `search_for` does not exist in `string`, the formula will return a `#REF!` error.  You can wrap the entire formula in an `IFERROR` function if you want.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, here is one method of being able to see both elements of the array.  The formula was entered in `C1:C2` as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`.  To understand better, I suggest accessing Excel Help regarding array formulas.

[image]

Comment: Very concise and much better!

Comment: Mmmm, for some reason, this only returns the starting position of the first occurrence. For example, for "John AND Bill AND Tom", the result was 6

Comment: @Alex  If you applied the formula correctly (and I cannot tell that from what you have supplied), and assuming `search_for` is `AND`, then the formula is returning the array `{6;15}`.   You can see this by selecting the cell with the formula; then place the cursor in the formula bar befor the `=`.  Then hit `F9`.  The method of accessing more than just the first element of a formula that returns an array depends, in part, on what you want to do with these values.

Comment: @Alex  I have added a screen shot demonstrating a method of having the formula returning both 6 and 15.  The method is the same as you would use if you were using the `LINEST` function to return more of the computed results.

Comment: @Alex If my response helped, kindly mark it as the Answer

Answer (score 1):

The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) and [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) cannot find the position of the *k* instance of a search term, only the first instance. However, the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) can replace the *k* instance of a search term with something completely unique and you can then search for that.

[image: Search for nth instance of string in string]

The formula in C3 is,

```
=FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill down as necessary. Use an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as a wrapper to catch the #VALUE! errors thrown when you run out of instances into an error message or an empty string.

I've used the [LOWER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOWER-function-3F21DF02-A80C-44B2-AFAF-81358F9FDEB4) with FIND as SUBSTITUTE is case-sensitive.

Expanded to the first 9 possible positions returned by FIND would make the formula,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CHAR(123) &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 1)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 2)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 3)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 4)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 5)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 6)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 7)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 8)) & CHAR(44), "") &
      IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A$2), LOWER(B$2), CHAR(215), 9)) & CHAR(44), "")
    & CHAR(125), CHAR(44)&CHAR(125), CHAR(125))
```

Result: `{1,16}` (change the braces to brackets with `CHAR(40)` and `CHAR(41)` in place of `CHAR(123)` and `CHAR(125)`)

Expanding this further would be a simple copy/paste/renumber operation.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes A1 has the phrase and B1 has the word you want to search for.  This formula will return an array of all starting character positions of the matches.

```
=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))),IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))),SEARCH(B1,A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")))/LEN(B1))))
```